# TimePicker on PCL Xamarin project getHour, getMinutes

Tags: c#, xamarin, cross-platform, timepicker

I am trying to get hour and minutes from a timepicker on Xamarin pcl project. I want to convert them to integers. Is there a getHour or getMinutes method that i can use? I cannot find it. I need this to work on the Portable project NOT on android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[TimePicker](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.TimePicker/) returns a [Timespan](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan(v=vs.110).aspx), which has Hours and Minutes properties

```
var time = myTimeSpan.Time;
int hour = time.Hours;
int min = time.Minutes;
```

Comment: Thank you sir. Do you know how to set the timePicker on the current time? (Device's time)

Comment: yes, set the Time property.  There is an example in the linked docs page

Answer (score 0):

As Jason says, [TimePicker](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.TimePicker/) returns a [Timespan](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan(v=vs.110).aspx), which has Hours and Minutes properties

```
var time = myTimeSpan.Time;
int hour = time.Hours;
int min = time.Minutes;
```

In the same way you can set the `Timespan` based on current time as follows:

```
timePicker.Time = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
```